# Is Entropic Warding a passive invocation and when is the effect over?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, eldritch-invocations

I was wondering if entropic warding is activated passively (meaning it is activated automatically upon recieving damage) or if it requires a standard action casting for it to be active just like the rest of the invocations. This is the description for the invocation:

> When this invocation is activated, chaotic energies swirl about you, 
>   deflecting incoming arrows, rays, and other ranged attacks (as
>   entropic shield). You leave no trail (as pass without trace) and
>   cannot be tracked by scent. (You can still be detected normally by
>   scent, just not tracked.)

From that description, I can't tell whether it is activated passively or through standard action like the rest of warlock invocations.

Also, after succesfully deflecting an attack via entropic warding, does it need to be cast again or does the effect continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The least invocation ***entropic warding*** (*Complete Arcane* 134) is a spell-like ability that takes a standard action to activate and that combines the effects of both the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell [*entropic shield*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#entropic-shield) [abjur] (*Player's Handbook* 227) and the 1st-level Drd spell [*pass without trace*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#pass-without-trace) [trans] (*PH* 259).

This means that the invocation's *entropic shield* effect has a duration of 1 min. per warlock arcane caster level and that the invocation's *pass without trace* effect has the *totally different* duration of 1 hour per warlock arcane caster level.

(This reader supposes the parenthetical was placed in the middle of this sentence of the invocation's description when it should've been placed at the end: "You leave no trail (as *pass without trace*) and cannot be tracked by scent." That is, the invocation says that the warlock can't be tracked by scent, but a creature affected by a *pass without trace* effect *already* can't be tracked by scent!)

To be clear, since the *entropic shield* effect functions like the spell, it remains active until its duration expires normally; for example, it need not be renewed after it successfully deflects an attack.

#### Consider relaxing the bookkeeping for the warlock with this invocation

As a warlock can employ the *entropic warding* invocation at will, this DM would typically allow a player to have his warlock automatically as a standing order spend a few seconds every 5 or 6 minutes or whatever to activate the invocation so that both of its effects are essentially active all the time while the warlock's awake.

Comment: That cleared out alot. Thanks!